# Highlight and scroll to random cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'd like to have a button that when pressed, will select a random item in a `UICollectionView`, and then scroll to it.

So far, I have this code:

```
@IBAction func randomClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    self.randomItem = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.members.count)))
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.randomItem, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
    })
}
```

This highlights the cell as I want (as I have set up styles in `cellForIndexAtItem)`, however the view doesn't scroll at all. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see what it is!

I have tried a simpler version, just to test the scroll bit:

```
@IBAction func randomClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 30, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

But again, there's no scrolling.

**Update: 27th Feb**
I've since recreated the entire view, but the problem still persists - no scrolling! Here is the full code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class GroupViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var random = -1
    // pick a single random student to scroll to
    @IBAction func randomClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        self.random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(200)))
        self.collectionView.reloadData() // reloads the visible cells, highlighting the random one
        self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: self.random, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
    // 200 example cells
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 200
    }
    // draw the cells
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.title.text = "Title"
        cell.subtitle.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.title.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.subtitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        if(random == indexPath.row) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        }
        return cell
    }
    // 4 columns per row
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = collectionView.frame.width
        return CGSize(width: (size/4)-(24/4), height: (size/4)-(24/4))
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you calling `reloadData` first ?

Comment: That causes the cells to reload - in cellForIndexAtItem, it will check to see if the current cell is the randomly selected one, and set it's colour accordingly.  Possibly not the best way to do that (open to suggestions!). However, even without that line, it's not working, so I'm assuming that's not the issue here?

Comment: the reload is asynchronous so it will likely have an impact on scrolling, i'd expect it to work without that unless you're reloading elsewhere. log the delegate methods to check what's called and when as you try to scroll

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense to me - however why would my second version not work, when `reloadData` isn't called?

Comment: if reloadData is a must you can scroll after it is finished. Check this, hope it helps.
self.collectionView.reloadData()

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow:self.randomItem, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }

Comment: Thanks Mihriban, as I say, I understand why you need to scroll after the `reloadData` - the problem I am having is that the scrolling does not happen at all, even if I remove the `reloadData`. Could it be to do with some layout constraints / stack view / something like that?

Comment: Are all of the items in your collection view visible? If so, scrolling might not be occurring because of this

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk Yes, they are - or at least they should be. On the viewController there is another view that is hidden though (both that view, and the view containing the collection view are within a stack view) - I assume that's nothing to do with it though?

Comment: @Ben I think the problem might be due to the fact that all items are already visible. Can you manually scroll your collection view?

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk Yeah I can. I've just re created that single view and the same thing happens. I'll post the entire code above just in case that helps.

Comment: Hi, wondering u have any solution update on this problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a collection view you would want to use.

```
NSIndexPath(forItem: 30, inSection: 0)
```

not, which is for table views.

```
NSIndexPath(forRow: 30, inSection: 0)
```